# How to read a .json file and write to a new file, inserting line breaks with Python

Tags: python, json

So I have a .json file that my script needs to work with. The problem is that my script is using linereaders to move through the input file, and the json file I have is all on one huge single line. Looking at the file, i'm not sure what I can do to locate where to create new lines. Does anyone know how I might do this? It's vital to my project that I can take this .json file (example one below), make it correctly formatted (or at least on new lines), and then read this as the input for the script. Thanks in advance

Example 1, The current way the .json file looks:

```
{"nodes":[{"nodeID":"119927","text":"Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:13"},{"nodeID":"119928","text":"Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119929","text":"But still Germany produces way too much rubbish","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119930","text":"and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119931","text":"We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119932","text":"Default Conflict","type":"CA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119933","text":"Default Inference","type":"RA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119934","text":"Default Conflict","type":"CA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"}],"edges":[{"edgeID":"160906","fromID":"119927","toID":"119932","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160907","fromID":"119932","toID":"119931","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160908","fromID":"119928","toID":"119933","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160909","fromID":"119933","toID":"119927","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160910","fromID":"119929","toID":"119934","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160911","fromID":"119934","toID":"119932","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160912","fromID":"119930","toID":"119934","formEdgeID":null}],"locutions":[]}
```

Example 2, The format that my script runs fine with:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "nodeID":20,
            "text":"Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time.",
            "type":"I"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":21,
            "text":"Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins.",
            "type":"I"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":22,
            "text":"But still Germany produces way too much rubbish",
            "type":"I"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":23,
            "text":"and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt.",
            "type":"I"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":24,
            "text":"We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!",
            "type":"I"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":40,
            "text":"Default Conflict",
            "type":"CA"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":41,
            "text":"Default Inference",
            "type":"RA"
        },
        {
            "nodeID":42,
            "text":"Default Conflict",
            "type":"CA"
        }
    ],
    "edges":[
        {
            "fromID":20,
            "toID":40
        },
        {
            "fromID":40,
            "toID":24
        },
        {
            "fromID":21,
            "toID":41
        },
        {
            "fromID":41,
            "toID":20
        },
        {
            "fromID":22,
            "toID":42
        },
        {
            "fromID":42,
            "toID":40
        },
        {
            "fromID":23,
            "toID":42
        }
    ],
    "schemefulfillments":[

  ],
    "participants":[

  ],
    "locutions":[

   ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't have time before the end of my project to completely rewrite my whole program, so it has to be done this way, or similar method that does not require significant rewrites to my original script.

Comment: Please post the code you're currently using so we can spot any problems.

Comment: That formatting is not required for valid JSON; maybe you should use a proper parser rather than rolling your own?

Comment: If your script chokes on valid JSON that is not pretty-printed something is **very** wrong with it and you need to fix that instead of prettyprinting it. Why doesn't your script use a JSON parser to parse JSON? And just FYI, in case this is a university assignment: I would probably fail you for using a JSON parser that cannot parse JSON ;)

Comment: ^ what @ThiefMaster said

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is not a university assignment in any regard for examining my ability to parse .json. It's for argumentation and I have already been told the script is fine using linereaders rather than parsing json with a library, as I said this would require an entire rewrite which at this stage is impossible. Is there any way to do what i'm asking?

Comment: If you really wrote your code in such a way that changing the parser is a huge task (I want to stress that it really shouldn't be), just write a parser to parse the valid JSON to pretty JSON. Simply add a newline after after symbol that isn't ":" and isn't enclosed in quotes. That'll give you the same amount of newlines (albeit, without the whitespace). This isn't really a website to write your code though, if you want such a script try to write it yourself then ask another question if you fail.

Comment: @user161778, Thanks I have done this. Managed to get the json outputted to a pretty format, and am now adapting the program to move through this. Thank you for the help

Comment: @SneakySpriggs No problem! Good luck on your future endeavors :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

Input:

```python
import json

compactJSON = """{"nodes":[{"nodeID":"119927","text":"Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:13"},{"nodeID":"119928","text":"Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119929","text":"But still Germany produces way too much rubbish","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119930","text":"and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt.","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119931","text":"We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!","type":"I","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119932","text":"Default Conflict","type":"CA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119933","text":"Default Inference","type":"RA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"},{"nodeID":"119934","text":"Default Conflict","type":"CA","timestamp":"2015-12-14 12:09:14"}],"edges":[{"edgeID":"160906","fromID":"119927","toID":"119932","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160907","fromID":"119932","toID":"119931","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160908","fromID":"119928","toID":"119933","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160909","fromID":"119933","toID":"119927","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160910","fromID":"119929","toID":"119934","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160911","fromID":"119934","toID":"119932","formEdgeID":null},{"edgeID":"160912","fromID":"119930","toID":"119934","formEdgeID":null}],"locutions":[]}"""

dictionary = json.loads(compactJSON)

prettyJSON = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

print(prettyJSON)
```

Output:

```
{
    "edges": [
        {
            "fromID": "119927",
            "edgeID": "160906",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119932"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119932",
            "edgeID": "160907",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119931"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119928",
            "edgeID": "160908",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119933"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119933",
            "edgeID": "160909",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119927"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119929",
            "edgeID": "160910",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119934"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119934",
            "edgeID": "160911",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119932"
        },
        {
            "fromID": "119930",
            "edgeID": "160912",
            "formEdgeID": null,
            "toID": "119934"
        }
    ],
    "locutions": [],
    "nodes": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:13",
            "nodeID": "119927",
            "text": "Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time.",
            "type": "I"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119928",
            "text": "Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins.",
            "type": "I"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119929",
            "text": "But still Germany produces way too much rubbish",
            "type": "I"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119930",
            "text": "and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt.",
            "type": "I"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119931",
            "text": "We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!",
            "type": "I"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119932",
            "text": "Default Conflict",
            "type": "CA"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119933",
            "text": "Default Inference",
            "type": "RA"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2015-12-14 12:09:14",
            "nodeID": "119934",
            "text": "Default Conflict",
            "type": "CA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

//Reading Json File From Directory

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\FilesDemo\\abc.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    JSONArray employeeList = new JSONArray();
    employeeList.add(obj);

    // Write JSON file
    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\FilesDemo\\employee.json")) {
        file.write(employeeList.toJSONString());
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```